# How to check if only one element from the table has specific class with Cypress

Tags: reactjs, typescript, radio-button, cypress

I have a table for emails with "primary" radiobuttons column which means only one of them could have class .checked. How can I check this with Cypress?

I tried this but it's not working for classes since it checks if all the elements in the column to have this class.

P.S I'm using TypeScript and React. Each row is rendered separately

```
  it("check if rest of the emails' primary setting are set to false", () => {
    cy.get('td:nth-child(2)')
    .should('not.have.class', 'checked')
    .should('have.length', 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the jQuery [:checked](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector

```js
cy.get('td:nth-child(2):checked')
  .should('have.length', 1)
```

Comment: Thanks! I redone it to 
cy.get('td:nth-child(2) .checked').should('have.length', 1);
And it worked for me!

Comment: @MaxIvanov i knew it is not relevant, i am just new to cypress, may i know how to understand nth-child(number), i see that a lot in cypress selector.

Comment: @AeLeung if I understood you correctly - you want to understand better how to use nth-child. If so - it's a basic HTML pseudoselector and you can read more about it on w3schools or Mozilla developer. Try to make some exercises using this selector. ChroPath extension could help you a lot to understand in more in-depth.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.php

Answer (score 0):

cy.get('td:nth-child(2) .checked').should('have.length', 1);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).